# Building regex to extract values

Tags: python, regex

```
list=[endpoint.av.GrisoftAV.activescan,endpoint.as.KasperskyAS.activescan,
endpoint.fw.ATTFW.description,
endpoint.av["360SafeAV"].activescan,
endpoint.av["H+BEDV"].description]
```

I need to build a regex to extract the values in third octet

The output needs to be:

```
GrisoftAV
KasperskyAS
ATTFW
360SafeAV
H+BEDV
```

Comment: Just split by `.` and use the array[2].

Comment: Hey i am kind of new to regex so it will be more helpful if you can just write down the regex so that i can test

Comment: What do you mean by "octet"?  Looks like you mean the third period-separated field.

Comment: Don't use regex.  http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/dictionary/python-split

Comment: FWIW the regex for full stop is `r'\.'` or `r'[.]'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
lst = ['endpoint.av.GrisoftAV.activescan','endpoint.as.KasperskyAS.activescan','endpoint.fw.ATTFW.description','endpoint.av["360SafeAV"].activescan','endpoint.av["H+BEDV"].description']

lst = [re.sub('[.\[\]]', ',', i) for i in lst]
lst = [re.sub('[\"]', '', i) for i in lst]
for i in lst:
    x = i.split(',')
    print x[2]
```

Here, we're using regex to convert the `.[]` to commas so that they are easy to split, and we get rid of the quotation inside the strings. Then we split the strings by the comma and retrieve the third elements.

Answer (score 0):

You do not really need regex for this.  Standard string manipulations will work just fine.

**Code:**

```
def find_octet(a_string):
    return a_string.replace('["', '.').replace('"]', '.').split('.')[2]
```

**Test Code:**

```
list = [
    'endpoint.av.GrisoftAV.activescan',
    'endpoint.as.KasperskyAS.activescan',
    'endpoint.fw.ATTFW.description',
    'endpoint.av["360SafeAV"].activescan',
    'endpoint.av["H+BEDV"].description']

for item in list:
    print(find_octet(item))
```

**Results:**

```
GrisoftAV
KasperskyAS
ATTFW
360SafeAV
H+BEDV
```